# PHP Laravel Routing Issue

Tags: php, url-routing, laravel, laravel-3

My setup currently looks like this

***application/controllers/register.php***

```
class register_Controller extends Base_Controller
{
    public $restful = true;
    public function get_index()
    {
        return View::make('main.register');;
    }
}
```

***routes.php***

```
Route::controller(Controller::detect());
Route::any('/', function()
{
    return View::make('main.index');
});
Route::any('register',function()
{
    return View::make('register.index');
});
```

mydomain.com works.

mydomain.com/index gives a laravel 404

mydomain.com/register gives a standard 404

What's strange is that shouldn't mydomain.com/register give me a laravel 404 error?
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791375/laravel-routes-not-working?rq=1) page indicates that WAMP was the cause, but my setup is on a Ubuntu VM running PHP5, Apache2, and mySQL.

Comment: The last route? What is it for other than to tread on the controllers toes... that coincidentally needs to be capitalised from my understanding of Laravel, `Register_Controller`. I can't see why it's not throwing a laravel 404 mind you.

Comment: I've already tried capitalizing, tried it without that last Route. I added it because nothing else works, and since routes are evaluated in the order presented it can't possibly tread on the controllers, right?
My feeling right now is that something's wrong with the PHP settings.

Comment: Capitalised is correct, at least in terms of all the Laravel docs I've read. I can tell you that the last route is totally unecessary. If the controller isn't being auto detected declare it: `Route::Controller(array('register'));`

Comment: Also is `register.php` in the controllers directory and not in a sub directory of it?

Comment: register.php is not in a subdirectory. I've tried both the array and the single routing method, both to no avail.

Comment: Laravel is supposed to catch all 404s right? /index gets caught but anything else does not. I still feel like there's some PHP/Apache configuration issues.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15590/discussion-between-david-barker-and-wonton)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With mod_rewrite on, try setting in apache configurations "AllowOverride All", it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

As Akash suggests, make sure your mod_rewrite is enabled.
On Ubuntu use the following command to enable mod_rewrite on Apache:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

(You don't have to edit httpd.conf)
Do not forget to restart apache.

You can use the PHP command

```
phpinfo();
```

to check if mod_rewrite is working.

Comment: phpinfo() confirms that mod_rewrite is loaded, but it still does not work. Would having it on Ubuntu as a virtualhost be a cause?

Comment: It works on my Mint Linux (which is an Ubuntu derivative). I cannot imagine why being on a virtual host could be the cause.

Comment: I got it! AllowOverride All fixed it

Answer (score 3):

make sure mod_rewrite is turned on in Apache (httpd.conf)

Un-comment the following line

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and restart httpd

Answer (score 2):

In addition, you should set your routes before you detect your controllers.

```
Route::any('/', function()
{
    return View::make('main.index');
});

Route::any('register',function()
{
    return View::make('register.index');
});

Route::controller(Controller::detect());
```