# Routing for subpages on production server not works

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am working on Lunux. My created locally webpage works good but after I sent on production server only mainpage is routing, subpages not.
For example address https://demo.tiltkomp.pl/ is working but https://demo.tiltkomp.pl/about return `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://demo.tiltkomp.pl/about"`

my `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('about', 'PagesController@about');
```

in `PagesController.php`:

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('pages.index');
    }

    public function about(){
        return view('pages.about');
    }
}
```

Where do I make mistake ?

Comment: you probably need to enable `mod_rewrite`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791375/laravel-routes-not-working?rq=1

Comment: Could be a permission error see link: https://laravel.com/docs/master/installation#configuration

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28031497/5130217

So in case you using Apache you need to check mod_rewrite enabled and Override allowed in apache2.conf file.